# Cluster lines sharing the same column 1 into one line

Tags: bash, line

I have a list. There are some lines whose Column 1 is the same.

```
ENSG00000005187 chr16   19  209 0.079
ENSG00000005187 chr16   20  206 0.172
```

I want to cluster those lines sharing the same Column 1 into one line like below:

```
ENSG00000005187 chr16   19  209 0.079  chr16    20  206 0.172
```

How can I do it using bash?

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `awk`:

```
awk '{ x[$1]=x[$1] " " $2 " " $3 " " $4 " " $5 } END { for (k in x) print k,x[k]; }' input.txt
```

That snippet assumes all your lines have exactly five fields.

By the way the `join` standard utility comes close to doing what you need, but unfortunately is designed to join two different files; joining a file with itself produces spurious lines. Nevertheless you should probably check it out because if you do this kind of task often you're bound to find it useful at some time.

Answer (score 0):

With this method, you don't have to store the entire file in memory:

```
sort file | awk '
  {
    if ($1 == current) {$1 = OFS; nl = ""}
    else {current = $1; if (NR>1) nl = "\n"} 
    printf("%s%s",nl,$0)
  }
  END {print ""}
'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed ':a;$!N;s/^\(\S*\)\( .*\)\n\1/\1\2/;ta;P;D' file
```

This assumes the file is sorted, if not just pipe sorted file through to this command.